# Google Docs api - We&#39;re sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try reloading your spreadsheet

Tags: google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I am having a problem using api for accessing google docs from today (now it lasts around 10h). When I call

```
SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQuery();
var mainFeed = service.Query(query);
```

I get a 500 response with a message:

> "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try reloading your spreadsheet."

What is interesting this happens only from the server machine and it works all fine  from my local one. Also when I open the sheets with the web browser it works. Only the api access suddenly stopped working. Does it mean the server was blocked?

Comment: Nothing showing up on the status page. http://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=status